# Swift Master-Detail Template Issues (iOS 8 beta 3)

Tags: ios, swift, uisplitviewcontroller

I am testing Swift Master-Detail template and I've found a few issues:

1. Testing in iPad portrait (simulator or real device), it always starts with detail view without the popup button. Rotating and back, the button appears. Is this normal? The button disappears again when I go into the detail View in Portrait mode. [Update: in iOS Beta 3, it now started with the button, but the button still disappeared after entering detail mode in Portrait]
2. The configureView is called multiple times when I select an item. On iPhone, it was called twice, on iPad, it was called 3 times! Is it normal?

   ```
   func configureView() {
       // Update the user interface for the detail item.
       if let detail: AnyObject = self.detailItem {
           println("Detail:\(detail)")  // print out 3 times on iPad
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of these issues have been resolved with the release of Xcode 6 beta 4.  I suggest you create a new project from the Swift Master-Detail template because the template code changed in beta 4.

Comment: Works! Still got some issues though (on iPad portrait, click on an item does not hide the left bar).